# Why non-const version is selected over the const version for class?

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, overload-resolution

Following is the test code:

```
struct A
{
  operator int ();
  operator int () const;
};

void foo (const int);
```

Now, upon invoking:

```
foo(A());  // calls A::operator int()
```

Why does it [always chooses the non-const version](http://www.ideone.com/X4HLT) ? Even making `operator const int () const;` doesn't have any effect on invoking `foo()`. Apart from standard reference, can someone explain logically, the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`A()` gives you a temporary `A` object that is not const-qualified.  The `A()` expression is an rvalue expression, yes, but that does not make the `A` object const-qualified.

Since the `A` object is not const-qualified, the non-const `operator int()` is an exact match and the const `operator int()` requires a qualification conversion, so the non-const overload is selected as the best match.

If you want it to be const-qualified, you'd need to explicitly request a const-qualified `A`:

```
foo(identity<const A>::type());
```

where `identity` is defined as

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

Note that there is really no difference between `operator const int() const` and `operator int() const`:  the result is an rvalue and only class-type rvalues can be const-qualified (`int` is not a class type).

Note also that there is no difference between the `void foo(const int)` that you have and `void foo(int)`.  Top-level const-qualifiers on parameter types do not affect the type of the function (i.e., the type of both of those declarations is `void foo(int)`).  Among other reasons, this is because it doesn't matter to the caller whether there is a top-level const-qualifier; it has to make a copy regardless.  The top-level const-qualifier affects only the definition of the function.

Comment: Even `A` being a normal stack/heap allocated object (not temporary), it gives the same result.

Comment: If the object isn't const-qualified, the non-const overload is a better match during overload resolution.  Is there a reason you would expect this not to be the case?

Comment: Why I get confused is, even if `foo()` receives `const int` and we have an `A::operator const int () const;`, still it goes and chooses the normal `A::operator int`.

Comment: @iammilind: The return type is not used in function resolution only the parameters. The only parameter is the `this` pointer.

Comment: `foo(const int)` and `foo(int)` are the same as far as the caller is concerned.  Top-level const qualifiers on function parameters are not part of the function's type.  (You can think about it this way:  the caller doesn't really care whether there is a top-level const-qualifier; it doesn't matter because it just has to know that a copy is going to be made.)

Comment: I suppose, perhaps, I am confused about what you are confused about.

Comment: @iammilind: "even if foo() receives const int..." - using const on the function parameter just means the function's implementation can't change it... it has no meaning outside the function, for call resolution or otherwise. @James: that identity thing seems to introduce an unnecessary layer of obfuscation compared to `const_cast<const A&>(A())`... any functional differences?  (I know some people insist `static_cast<>` should be used for that, and disagree)

Comment: @Tony:  Well, everyone should have an `identity` template anyway; it's superlatively useful.  :-)  It has the benefit of not being a cast; if no cast is needed then no cast should be used.  Even if one wanted to use a "cast"-like thing, `implicit_cast` would be preferable.  `static_cast` and `const_cast` are dangerous and should only be used where necessary.

Comment: @James: ah yes, `implicit_cast` is very suitable - hope it makes it from boost to the Standard one day. Personally, I find the `const_cast<>` much more expressive of what I'm trying to achieve than the `identity` template, but these days I often work in higher level code ( :-( ) that doesn't have many, or has very well encapsulated, `volatile` variables... so I've no concerns about accidentally removing volatility (which is the only danger).

Answer (score 5):

[James McNellis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515418/why-non-const-version-is-selected-over-the-const-version-for-class/6515423#6515423)’ answer really covered it all, but it doesn’t hurt (I hope) with more explanations.

So.

When you call …

```
    o.operator int()
```

… then the overload selection depends entirely on *the constness of `o`*.

Nothing else.

To see why, consider this class:

```
struct Bar
{
    void f() {}
    void f() const {}
};
```

Technically those member functions do not need to be member functions. They could just as well have been chosen to be free standing functions. But then they need `Bar` argument:

```
struct Bar
{};

void f( Bar& ) {}
void f( Bar const& ) {}
```

And hopefully now it's easier to see that when you do

```
Bar o;
f( o );
```

then the first function *can* be selected. And so it is. Because if the second function was selected, then you could never get the first one. Because if you make the object `const`, then it would break `const` correctness to select the first one. So when the object is `const` only the second can be selected, hence, when it is not `const` the first one is selected.

In short, the only practical alternative to this rule would be to always select the second one, which would make the first one rather useless, yes?

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: If the non-const version is made private, it still tries to use that one rather than the public const version, with resultant "attempting to access private member" error! So annoying.

Answer (score 4):

One rule you have to remember about C++: it **never** takes into account the value that is being returned when it selects an overload. In this case since the `operator int` function takes no parameters, it can't use the parameter list to narrow down the choices either. All it can use it the constness of the object that it's being called from. Since this is a new temporary object, it's not const, so it doesn't choose the const overload.

Comment: *Never* is perhaps too strong; the return type is taken into account when resolving overloading when taking the address of a function, and when resolving conversion operators for an automatic conversion.  (The latter can be quite useful when you want to have a function overloaded on return type.  Have it return a proxy with different conversion operators.)